# How to add document to a collection dynamically?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on accounting system, and I want the user to create accounts in the chart of accounts dynamically, and whenever a new account is created the app creates a new collection for that account.
Here's an example:

```
    const account = new Chart({
    name: accountName,
    category: accountCategory
});
```

Now an account is created and added to charts collection, but I need to create a collection for that account, I tried calling a new method to create that collection and it works like this

```
const createModel = (accountName)=>{
const newModel = mongoose.model(accountName, ledgerSchema);
}
```

It creates a model, I can add a document to it right away after creating it like this:

```
const createModel = (accountName)=>{
const newModel = mongoose.model(accountName, ledgerSchema);
const record = new accountName({
some_value: 100
});
record.save();
}
```

The problem is, I can't create any documents and add it to that model afterwards, it only works when I'm declaring and creating the model, but after that if I tried to write:

```
const record = new accountName({
some_value: 100
});
record.save();
}
```

In any other function or after the app is closed it won't work, it says the the accoutName is not defined.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the model created till the connection is open.  Otherwise you need to create a new instance again.
Refer [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) for more details